# Spring Scheduled Task

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to create a Scheduled task with Spring, but I'm probably not doing something correctly exposing the @Bean in configuration. My code is as follows:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:hibernate.properties")
@EnableJpaRepositories("org.app.repository")
@ComponentScan("org.app")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableScheduling
public class JpaConfiguration {

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER = "db.driver";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL = "db.url";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.username";

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.show_sql";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN =
            "entitymanager.packages.to.scan";

    @Resource
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(
                env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {

        // will set the provider to 'org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence'
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        // will set hibernate.show_sql to 'true'
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
        // if set to true, will set hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto to 'update'
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emfBean = new
                LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        emfBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        emfBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        emfBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(
                org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);

        emfBean.setPackagesToScan(
                env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN));

        emfBean.setJpaProperties(hibProperties());

        return emfBean;
    }

    private Properties hibProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT,
                env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL,
                env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler ts = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        ts.initialize();
        ts.setPoolSize(8);
        ts.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
        return ts;
    }
}

@Component
public class MainBean {

    @Autowired
    private MyRunnable myRunnable;

    @Autowired
    private CategoryRepo categoryRepo;

    @Autowired
    private ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler;

    public void start() {

            //This works
        categoryRepo.findAll().forEach(System.out::println);


        //this throws an exception
        taskScheduler.execute(myRunnable);

        //if i use an infinite loop here in order to prevent 
        //the method from exiting everything works normal
        // while(true) {
        //    Thread.sleep(10000000);
        // }
        System.out.println("Application Started. . .");
    }
}
```

**Category Repo**

```
public interface CategoryRepo extends JpaRepository<Category, String> {

}
```

**Runnable**

```
@Component
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {



    @Autowired
    private CategoryRepo categoryRepo;

    @Override
    public void run() {


        try {
            List<Category> list = categoryRepo.findAll();
            list.forEach(System.out::println);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Also if I dont use a scheduler and I just do

```
myRunnable.run();
```

it executes normally.

Anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong, or maybe an alternative way in doing this?

EDIT: My pom.xml dependencies are as follows (Spring is 4.0.2 as you can see in the properties tag):

```
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring.version>4.0.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!--Hibernate Dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Spring  Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <!--CGLIB is required to process @Configuration classes-->
        <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Other Dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.28</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
```

And Java is 1.8 - also tried with 1.7 and had same results

**EDIT:**

Apparently I think the issue is that the program is exiting and it leaves the Spring Context. Therefore when the runnable is executed, the thread cant find the entitymanager.

If I use an infinite while loop right before the MainBean exits then everything executes normally

Comment: Please post the library versions you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I havent found any satisfactory answers unfortunately. The only unorthodox solution (in my opinion) I have found is to do an infinite loop that doesnt allow the program to exit as follows:

```
public void start() {

    System.out.println("Application Started. . .");

    taskScheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(myRunnable, Date.from(Instant.now()),
            TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1));

    while (true) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue and noticed that if I replace the repo with a DAO that uses the @PersistenceContext annotation it works fine. No idea why it won't execute repo methods.

Answer (score 2):

The root cause is

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.app.config.JpaConfiguration.setBeanFactory(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory;)V
```

A `NoSuchMethodError` almost always indicates that there is a versioning issue with your build. The application tries to execute a method that was available at compile time, but not at run time. In other words, the classpath at compilation is different than the classpath at run time.

`spring-data-jpa` version [`1.5.1.RELEASE`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa/1.5.1.RELEASE) is compiled with Spring 3.2.8, but you're providing Spring libraries of `4.0.2.RELEASE`. However, it is built in a way that it will delegate to your project's actual dependencies if those exist. In your current setup, it will use the following

```
<artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
<artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
<artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
<artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
<artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
```

with version `4.0.2.RELEASE`, but it will use version `3.2.8.RELEASE` of

```
<artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
<artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
```

These are typically dependencies of `spring-context` with the same version, but here it seems they get overwritten by `spring-data-jpa`.

The simplest, but maybe incomplete (depending on the rest of your configuration), is to specifically declare those two dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

So `spring-data-jpa` will now delegate to these.

Alternatively, unless you are using some features of Spring `4.0.2.RELEASE`, you could get rid of all your other Spring dependencies and only keep `spring-data-jpa`. It will be responsible for pulling the other Spring `3.2.8.RELEASE` libraries.

Comment: I tried both solutions. It still provides the same error by including the two missing dependencies. I cant really use the other solution since 3.2.8 doesnt support Java 1.8 which I want to use.

Comment: @ChrisGeo Are you sure it's the exact same error? I tried with the code you've shown and it works for me. Maybe you have something else interfering?

Comment: Apparently the error has something to do with JPA, if I run a simple runnable like System.out.println("Something") it's ok. I will update with a bit of the JPA code in case you can spot something

Comment: Updated the initial code with some other cases, and the all the code having to do with JPA.

Comment: @ChrisGeo When you say it doesn't work, it just doesn't print anything?

Comment: The lambdas dont print anything...but that's probably because they are not managed by the Spring container. The last case however where I'm executing the Runnable which is a @Component, throws the exception. This statement: taskScheduler.execute(myRunnable);

Comment: @ChrisGeo Are you sure `categoryRepo.findAll()` returns a non-empty collection? I don't know how you use `EntityManager` and manage transactions but you should probably look into that since the call is done within a separate thread.

Comment: I'm sure since if I call it in the main thread it prints everything bormally. When it's in the other thread it crashed on that staement. The entitymanager and transactions are supposedly handled automatically through spring-data as you can see in the JpaConfiguration file.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a known bug on spring boot or Spring 4.
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/253

As it seems, the scheduler masks the real problem thrwing this strange error.

In your case, as it just happens with the scheduler, I would try to make a exception breakpoint to find out which kind of exception is being thrown in this case that is being hidden.